# How can I make Svelte for VSCode extension take my prettier configuration and apply it to my svelte files when formatting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, format, svelte, prettier

I have created a Svelte project two weeks ago and I wanted to format my code with the Prettier extension in VSCode, I had to add this to my settings.json (I have made sure it was to User configuration):

```
"[svelte]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "svelte.svelte-vscode"
}
```

And that was all I had to do and it started formatting all my Svelte files with the settings I had added previously in my settings.json.
Today I created another Svelte project and when I format, it isn't applying the settings I have but 'default' settings and I can't make it to work with the format rules I want.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Prettier settings normally go into a `.prettierrc` file at the root of the project. Those settings should be picked up by the extension.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but it doesn't work. For example, I'm trying not to use semicolon at the end of each line and I typed this in my .prettierrc:
`{ "semi": false }` but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem adding a .prettierrc.json file at the root of my project. The extension was throwing an error when using only .prettierrc (even if written in JSON format).
Thank you for seeing my question.

Comment: Weird - sveltekit has the same problem, even now.